# After transition to the new version android-ndk-r19 arises the error

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

After transition the error in the code falls:

```
C:/Jenkins/workspace/MeCode/src/CMake/openal/../../openal_android/common\math_defs.h:26:21: error: static declaration of 'log2f' follows non-static declaration
  static inline float log2f(float f)
                      ^
C:/android_sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/local/include\math.h:38:15: note: previous declaration is here
  float         log2f(float);
                ^
1 error generated.
FAILED: C:\android_sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 --gcc-toolchain=C:/android_pack/android_sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -Dopenal_EXPORTS -
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in the openal source. It can't define `log2f` as an inline if it has an out-of-line declaration elsewhere.